# Getting total Number of User Items in Firebase Realtime database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend, counter

I have been trying to get amount of users that have same "referralId" in my firebase Realtime database,

```
users {
  AY35bkc5cbkufik8gfe3vjbmgr {
    email: james @gmail.com
    verify: none
    referralid: AY35ja35
  }
  B16fty9jDchfNgdx7Fxnjc5nxf5v {
    email: mobilewisdom @gmail.com
    verify: none
    referralid: AY35ja35
  }
}
```

How can I use JavaScript to count the amount of account with `referralid:AY35ja35`
I tried:

```
      const query = ref.orderByChild('referralid').equalTo('AY35ja35');
      query.get().then((results) => {
       console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
      results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

But am getting this error in my console:
`Uncaught TypeError: query.get is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v8/namespaced syntax that'd be:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
const query = ref.orderByChild('referralid').equalTo('AY35ja35');
const results = await query.get();
console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
results.forEach((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
});
```

Or if you're in an environment where `await` doesn't work:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
const query = ref.orderByChild('referralid').equalTo('AY35ja35');
query.get().then((results) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

In v9/modular syntax the equivalent would be:

```
const ref = ref(getDatabase(), 'users');
const query = query(ref, orderByChild('referralid'), equalTo('AY35ja35'));
const results = await get(query);
console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
results.forEach((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
});
```

Or if you're in an environment where `await` doesn't work:

```
const ref = ref(getDatabase(), 'users');
const query = query(ref, orderByChild('referralid'), equalTo('AY35ja35'));
get(query).then((results) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Did you search for that error message yet? That's what I'd recommend in general when you get an error message, as you may find why that error occurs and how you can fix it. For example, this article: [How to use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) --- I now also added alternatives to my answer that use `then` instead of `await`.

Comment: I got another error message

Comment: I tried this one:```const ref = ref(getDatabase(), 'users');
const query = query(ref, orderByChild('referralid'), equalTo('AY35ja35'));
get(query).then((results) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(results.val()).length);
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
  });
}); ```And the error was "ref not defined"

Comment: This line is gonna be trouble `const ref = ref(getDatabase(), 'users');`, as you're using `ref` twice here: one is a function from Firebase, the other as the name of a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will have to run a query to get the data from firebase using either firebase package, axios or fetch

Your data is fetched in form of Object containing different objects. You can either user for .. in .. loop to iterate through the object.

```
var count = 0
for (const user in users) {
    if (user.referralid==="AY35ja35") {
       count++
    }
}
```

Or use Object.values(object) function to get array of users. Now you can use a JavaScript array function such as map or filter.

by using map. you can do it like this:

```
var count=0
user.map(user=>{if(user.referralid==="AY35ja35"){count++})
```

or by using filter

```
const matchedUsers = user.filter(user=>(user.referralid==="AY35ja35"))
const count = matchedUsers.length
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please how do I get data from the database I have been doing research on how to get it  but still haven't gotten any relevant answer